# Disabling specific controls on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've looked all over, even scoured documentation, and I'm having trouble finding an answer to a seemingly simple problem.

```
    Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType <> acComboBox Then
        If ctl.Name <> "SrchVal" Then
            ctl.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

I have a ton of textbox controls on my form which are being used for data entry. They should all be locked (disabled) until a certain button is clicked, an event I'll handle later.

However, there are a few combo box controls and one text box control I don't want disable, titled `SrchVal`.

I know that the Control object doesn't have an Enabled property, so how do I solve this?

Comment: ctl!Enabled = False

Comment: I received the following runtime error: `Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object`

Comment: What is the issue with your code?

Comment: The line `Ctl.Enabled = False` is raising errors

Comment: Is it possible some of the controls on your form don't have an Enabled property?

Comment: Not all control types have an Enabled property. You will need to check that the control is of the correct type before changing the Enabled property. (e.g. Checkbox, Combobox, Textbox, Subform)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Debug.Print TypeName(ctl)
    If TypeName(ctl) <> "ComboBox" Then ' <-- check if control is not a Combo-Box
        Debug.Print ctl.Name
        If ctl.Name <> "SrchVal" Then
            ctl.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

Comment: I'm still receiving an error on the line `ctl.Enabled = False`

Comment: @Steven I just full tested it and it ran fine, can you share the rest of the user_form code ?

Comment: @Steven try edited code, let me know what you are getting in the immediate window when you get your erro

Comment: `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.` I changed the Enabled property to Visible and it worked fine.